# Plot positions with different shades

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a file `polar.dat` that contains 3 columns : the first one is time, second is radius `r`, and third is polar angle `theta`. I want to plot the positions (r,theta) so that the points have different shade of color according to time. For example, using red, I want the very first positions to be in light red and the ultimate one in dark red.

I'm using python, pylab, and matplotlib so I'm looking for a command provided by these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use [matplotlib colorbar](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html) to show the colours. You will have to specify `time` in the `color` option in `scatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rc('font',family='serif')

time = np.random.random(100)
radius = np.random.random(100)
theta = np.random.random(100)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax1.scatter(radius,theta,c=time,s=40,cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
ax1.set_xlabel('radius')
ax1.set_ylabel('theta')
plt.colorbar(im,ax=ax1)

fig.show()
```

You can check the various `colormap` options available [at this website.](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) **For your specific case here, we are using `Reds`.**
[image]

Comment: And if I want to have shades of a single color instead of different colors ?

Comment: Here the colours are specified according to your `time` variable. What do you mean by "shades of a single colour"?

Comment: @dada: If my answer works, don't forget to accept it